# Last row of a MySQL result array breaks into strange array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table being drawn from a MySQL database with 4 fields: `id`, `postcode`, `blacklist_reason`, `signup_attempts`.

I then have the following class to output and deal with this, `$MySQL` is a mysql class with `ExecuteSQL` returning an array, not a MySQL resource.

```
class Blacklist {

private $MySQL = null;
private $rowsPerPage = 6;

public function __construct( $MySQL ) {

    $this->MySQL = $MySQL;

}

public function displayBlacklistList( $page = 1 ) {

    ( $page == 1 ) ? $start = 0 : $start = $this->rowsPerPage*($page-1);

    $finish = $this->rowsPerPage;           

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blacklist LIMIT $start, $finish";
    $res = $this->MySQL->ExecuteSQL($sql);

    echo '
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Add row</a></p>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Postcode</th>
                <th>Blacklist reason</th>
                <th>Signup attempts</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>';

    foreach( $res as $k => $v ) {
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$v['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$v['postcode'].'</td>
            <td>'.$v['blacklist_reason'].'</td>
            <td>'.$v['signup_attempts'].'</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>';
    }

    echo '
    </tbody>
    </table>';

    echo $this->_displayPagination( $page, $res );
}
}
```

Everything works and displays as expected unless I have, for example, 6 rows in the DB and set `$this->rowsPerPage = 5` as this causes the second page (showing one final row) to loop and show as many rows as there are fields in the table, with the data in each cell being the first character of the expected result. If I have 10 rows in the table and show 9 per page, the same happens, etc.

For example I get this:

```
ID  Postcode    Blacklist reason    Signup attempts
7   7           7                   7
B   B           B                   B
A   A           A                   A
6   6           6                   6
```

When I would expect:

```
ID  Postcode    Blacklist reason    Signup attempts
7   BH233SF     A reason            6
```

The issue is obviously with the `foreach()` loop, I'm used to using a `while( mysql_fetch_assoc() )` loop here but in this instance am using a class that returns arrays, not objects and I can't figure out why this is happening.

-- ANSWERS TO QUESTIONS --

`executeSQL` returns an associative array:

```
Array ( [id] => 7 [postcode] => BH233SF [blacklist_reason] => A reason [signup_attempts] => 6 )
```

What it is returning is fine, as var_dump also proves:

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["postcode"]=> string(7) "BH233SF" ["blacklist_reason"]=> string(8) "A reason" ["signup_attempts"]=> string(1) "6" }
```

Comment: It shows first characters of each column?.. Have you tried `var_dump($res)` ?

Comment: What does the ExecuteSQL method return?

Comment: Have added extra info to bottom of question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work it the way you want you should have

```
array(
    0 => array(
        "id" => "7", 
        "postcode" => "BH233SF", 
        "blacklist_reason" => "A reason", 
        "signup_attempts" => "6")
);
```

Otherwise your `foreach` loop iterates through the columns not the rows and that's why it gets messy.

Comment: Yea, I think this is the issue. The MySQL class returns just a single array if it only has one result, rather than a multidimensional one which it returns for multi rowed results.. Thanks - let me do some more digging

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Apparently your `Mysql` object is returning an associative array directly when performing a query with only one result. Therefore in the case where there's only one page you should avoid the foreach loop directly and just print out the result values. Alternatively you can just declare `$res` to be an array of one single value in case `$page == 1`:

```
if ($page == 1)
    $res = array($res);
```

**Why it was behaving like that**

Your `$res` array is an hash with paired key-values. This means that `foreach ($res as $a => $b)` would iterate over each one of the keys in the array (4 keys = 4 times) having `$b` to be the value corresponding to `$a` key. In your case `$b` is always a string therefore `b[...]` is considered as selecting a single character from the string. The `$v['id']` is for example converted to `$v[0]` (because `(int) 'id'` = `0`), returning the first char.

Comment: The `$v` in the foreach loop has the exact same value if you use `foreach ($res as $k => $v)` or `foreach ($res as $v)`  The only difference between the two is the `$k` which is the index of the value http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks for the help, the lack of dimensions to the array is the issue.. i've just removed the part of the class that returns results in different formats, seems more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Your database class seems to be returning an array of arrays when you have multiple rows, but just a single unnested row when there is only one.

So on the first page the `foreach` loop returns a row in $v while one the final page with only value it is instead looping through the row itself.

If you specify an index on a string it returns a character in that position, because the literal 'id' is not a valid number it translates to zero (false), so `$v['id']` is effectively being treated as `$v[0]` and as such returning the first character of the string.  The same is occurring for the other values.

If you cannot modify the class to always return the single row in an array for consistency (which would be the ideal solution) then you need to check whether one row has been returned and then nest the result yourself.  If the class does not have a way of returning a row count then you can just do this:

```
if (isset($res['id']))
   $res = array($res);
```

Comment: This works to turn the single array into a multi array, however I get an "Undefined offset: 0" notice - any idea how I can remove this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you only had an associative array, so there are no numbered elements when single rows are returned..  I have updated the answer to test using `isset($res['id'])` instead.  This will false without any error if it does not exist, but if it does then you know it is a single row of data rather than nested arrays.